# Parrot OS cannot install libc6 dependant libraries

Tags: steam, parrotsec

First of all, I really need to mention that I am a complete newbie to linux and decided to use debian and parrot OS solely for educational purpose to understand how everything works more.

Now to the problem: When I try to download steam (I tried downloading through APT and from the *.deb package on the official site) I get a bunch of errors (the held packages ones) with some libraries like `libgl1-mesa-dri:i386`, `libvulkan1:i386` etc. I have enabled multiarch for i386.

I have been googling the cause for a week now and nothing worked for me: multiarch, apt -f install, viewing held packages just returns nothing and I am all out of ideas now.

When I was looking for possible causes, I found that almost every library that causes troubles have a strange '50' pin-priority in `apt-cache policy`, so maybe I am downloading for a wrong version, but I could not find any relevant one.

Also I have to mention that I am new to the forum culture since previously all of my problems would have been solved by someone else already, so if I'm missing something important please tell me.
Thanks in advance!

Parrot OS version is 5.2
Debian 11
Main architecture is amd64

Comment: Parrot is a special purpose Cybersecurity operations OS. It's neither did for beginners, boot is supporting games anywhere even close to what it intended to do. So, long story short: replace parrot with a more general purpose Linux distro, and things will both work much smoother, and you will have something that other people at least try to use with steam.

Comment: The fact that in your first sentence you say you're a newbie when it comes to Linux and then later on say you were working with the intricate details of multiarch debian packaging would be hilarious if it wasn't frustrating for you, a real human being, who now must think everything you do on Linux is that complicated. It is not. You just chose to cross the ocean in a bathtub, although well-maintained ships were available :( now the ugly truth is that parrot is based on debian, but is not the same as debian, so that this failing is actually expectable :(

Comment: Solution: don't try to run games on a small distro optimized for a diametrally different use case, especially when said software expects the full multiarch debian software multiverse, which parrot simply cannot offer. Fixing your title in that regard - debian 11 should work; the fact that parrot os does not stems from the fact that it is not that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have to admit that the second comment is pretty hilarious and hits the nail on the head. Anyway, as Marcus mentioned, you should stick to one of the regular distros; if you're new to Linux, thing are going to be complicated enough (compared to Windows/Mac) anyway. Not that it is super-complicated, but it's just very different.

Comment: Welcome to U&L. This isn't actually a discussion forum. SE sites are Q&A sites - think of these as sort of remote support service run by volunteers :-) These work a bit differently from forums. I'd suggest taking the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour), checking the Asking and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) and generally hanging around, checking questions, comments and answers. That's the best way to learn the ropes.